# Node.js and MySQL query issues

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I am having trouble returning results when running queries on my MySQL database using Node.js. Below is an example of my code, which currently outputs **nothing** to the console.

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
password: '',
database: 'tl'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query = ('SELECT * from employees', function(error, results, fields) {
if (!error) {
    console.log(results);
} else {
    throw error;
}
});

connection.end();
```

1. Authentication is correct.
2. The database and table are not empty. Running the same query in MySQL itself returns rows.
3. The code below will give me 'Connection established':

   ```
   con.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log('Error connecting to Db');
     return;
    }
    console.log('Connection established');
   });
   ```

There is nothing wrong with my DB or table, all is working as expected, apart from running these queries. I've followed the official documentation and others

Comment: The syntax is wrong, it should be 
`connection.query('SELECT * from employees', function(error, results, fields) {...})`

Comment: Thank you! This solved the issue